# Como funciona os sockets no php

Tags: php, jquery

Eu tenho precisado ultimamente trabalhar com atualizações em tempo real, daí dando uma fuçada na internet descobri os sockets, mais especificadamente para utilizar em php. Estou fazendo um exemplo simples com base [nesses códigos](https://github.com/paulobordignon/socketphp), o problema é que ao enviar o formulário a página gera refresh do mesmo jeito, no caso eu teria que usar o jQuery.ajax para enviar a requisição sem refresh? Estou meio perdido.

---

Entendi mais ou menos como funciona depois de uma longa fuçada na internet, porém ao enviar uma mensagem com socket.send() o servidor retorna isso:  **GET / HTTP/1.1 Host: 127.0.0.1:3500 Connection: Upgrade Pragma: no-cache Cache-Control: no-cache Upgrade: websocket Origin: http://127.0.0.1 Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13 User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36 Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br Accept-Language: pt-BR,pt;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4 Sec-WebSocket-Key: 9cUxYx7abplnX8+wXBvZug== Sec-WebSocket-Extensions: permessage-deflate; client_max_window_bits**

Comment: Você quer simplesmente enviar um formulário sem refresh? Porque se você quiser fazer uma aplicação em tempo real, você realmente precisaria de uma estrutura maior, como Node.js + Socket.io, mas se você só quer que não dê refresh ao enviar um formulário, pode ser feito simplesmente com AJAX, sim.

Comment: Na verdade eu estava pensando em um jogo simples, para jogar com os amigos, onde o personagem se movimenta e tudo mais, como eu já desenvolvo com php a algum tempo, me senti mais confortável em desenvolver com ela. Os sockets do php não podem trabalhar dessa maneira? Digo, não é possível criar um jogo simples com os sockets php? Se não, qual linguagem você me recomendaria? Eu estava pensando em Ruby, ouvi falar muito bem a seu respeito.

Comment: Para jogos você vai precisar usar sockets, sim. Eu não entendo muito de sockets, mas sei que com AJAX vai pesar e ficar com delay (ping) alto. Eu recomendo que dê uma olhada no que já citei acima: Node.js + Socket.io    Essa dupla é muito usada em aplicações real-time. As duas tecnologias têm documentação disponível na internet e são baseadas em javascript.